# Can't load user profile from Internet chatroom on mobile

Tags: bug, android-app, mobile-web

When I touch usernames in chat on mobile web it brings up the SE app and then leaves me with a blank white page. When touching other links the app opens and then loads the appropriate page. When navigating to a user profile from within the app it functions properly.

**Some specifications:**

- Samsung Galaxy J7 Prime - (Phone)
- Android 7
- Samsung Internet 6
- Stack Exchange app - not Stack Overflow

Comment: No repro on my Moto G 2nd Gen, running Android 6.0.

Comment: Have you tried deleting its cache & data, then sign-in again?

Comment: @user.dz I changed phones a while ago and get no-repro on my current phone.